# Is there a way to start iOS app with the initial orientation dynamically?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiinterfaceorientation

I know that we can define main orientation in iOS apps. However I couldn't figure out a way to do what I want: If the device is in landscape mode, start the whole application in landscape mode. If not, start it in portrait.

Currently, if I start the application after rotating the device into landscape mode, It opens in portrait mode than it rotates. Is there a way to start the whole app in landscape? (Already rotated window)

Comment: This is a question that I'm interested in, as well. I have an app that I'm writing that I want to be universal. If you launch it on an iPhone, I want it to be landscape, and hide some stuff. On iPads, I want it to be portrait, and show everything. I want this to be dynamic, and am willing to write the code to support it. I am just unsure of where the hooks live.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; just indicate that you support all device orientations in your info.plist. You can see this in Xcode in your project settings under "General" in Xcode 5.

Comment: I already have set it to support all orientations, however it works (rotates) only after starting the application in portrait mode as @juniperi said. As you've written "Yes", I still hope there is some way out there. :|

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding you; do you mean that the user *sees* the app opening in portrait and then rotating? If you configure your info plist as well as your root view controller to support all orientations, the system should rotate to landscape, as juniperi points out, before the user sees anything. (Are you trying to avoid this *invisible* rotation? If so, why?)

Answer (score 0):

Quote from Apple's [UIViewController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW57):

> **Note: At launch time, apps should always set up their interface in a portrait orientation.** After the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method returns, the app uses the view controller rotation mechanism described above to rotate the views to the appropriate orientation prior to showing the window.

Comment: I don't think is the case any longer. In iOS7/8, if you remove the portrait and upside-down options, the app starts in landscape mode, and you need to select a launch image accordingly.